# Rails url_ for in nested resources _and_ namespace, is url_for generating wrong urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, namespaces

Lets assume the following nested resources with a namespace (I am enforced to use a TLA [three letter acronym] as namespace for sub projects/sub apps)

so I have this in `routes.rb`:

```
  namespace :ldc do
      resources :pubowners do
          resources :pubs
          resources :companies
      end
      resources :pubs, except: :new
  end
```

the model looks like this:

```
class Ldc::Pubs < ActiveRecord::Base
class Ldc::Pubowners < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and so on, since all are created via scaffold, all is looking nice and works ...

... as long as i select my pathes "manualy" like that:

```
- url=@pub.persisted? ? ldc_pubowner_pub_url(@pub.pubowner): ldc_pubowner_pubs_url(@pub.pubowner)
= form_for @pub, url: url  do |f|
   ...
```

I think this is nasty ...

Stepping into deeper I found out, that `url_for` or better `build_named_route_call` in polymorphic_routes.rb, just ignores (or does not to) the namespace of the second element of the input, ie. the same namespace is added twice (or more). so following examples:

```
link_to @pub -> /ldc/pub/1
link_to @pubowner -> /ldc/pubowner/17
link_to [@pubowner,@pub]  -> /ldc/pubowner/17/ldc/pub/1    < wrong should be ../17/pub/1
```

EDIT:

```
link_to [@pubowner,@pub] -> error no route for "ldc_pubowner_ldc_pub_url"
```

the last one where correct if routes.rb would look like this.

```
  namespace :ldc do
      resources :pubowners do
          namespace :ldc do
             resources :pubs
             resources :companies
          end
      end
      resources :pubs, except: :new
  end
```

So my conclusion is, that `url_for` or better `build_named_route_call` generate urls that do not exist when you have namespaced **and** nested resources.

Is this - my assumbtion - correct?